# freePBX CDR on remote database failing to connect

Tags: mysql, asterisk, freepbx

Morning all,

I have just finished a fresh install of freePBX and am trying to get the CDR to use a remote database without any luck.

I have tested the connection to the remote DB using mysql -u USERNAME -h REMOTE_IP -p'PASSWORD' and it connects fine.  However when I try to get the CDR to work it fails out saying access denied to the user.

I have used the 'Advanced Settings' to change the remote CDR DB details and this has done nothing, I have also edited the amportal.conf and the odbc.ini and still nothing.

What the hell am I missing, I really need to solve this quick if I can.

Cheers,

Blinky

Comment: Have you tried turning it on and off again??

Comment: As far as i know, for Asterisk you have to create a user and a database withe the name `Asterisk`, then Grant all privileges to the new user on that database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give database permission to remote user:

`grant all on your_database.* to username@'remote_ip' identified by 'password';`